# How to manage products in category on store view Basis

Tags: magento2, category-products

I have multiple store views with same root category, also with the same categories for all the store-views. Can we add different products in a category on the basis of store view.

If not, is there any way to do the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add different products to the same categories on different stores views.

A workaround would be to duplicate the categories, assign different products to them and disable them based on store view. The drawback here is that you won't be able to use the same URL key for them.

Maybe it's useful to mention that you could use rewrites to 'mimic' the same URL key in the stores (say if you want to the same url_key in the menu or somewhere else), here's how to: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/url-rewrite-product.html